# how can i display my sentence in python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

how can i display a sentence in the my program ..

if i have this sentence: " i play football" and i want to replace a letter "o" for example with "e"....

i do that with the following code and that code Displays the Adjustments that it did on the sentence for example :" feetball" but doesn't Display the sentences for example:
"i play feetball"
 how can i display the complete sentence after editting

the code that i use:
ــــــــــــــــــ

```
f="ذهب الولد إلى الشاطىء و تحدث بشكل هادىء و كان يسيير في بطئ و يمسك في يده شيئ"
x=f.split()

for s in x:
  if s.endswith("ئ") and len(s)==3 :
    print(s.replace("ئ","ء"))
  if s.endswith("ىء") and len(s)>=5:
    print(s.replace("ىء","ئ"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) doesn't change the original string, it returns a new one; strings are immutable in Python. Also, you don't actually change the original list of strings `x`, so you can't get the complete sentence. Try using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, s in enumerate(x):
    if s.endswith("ئ") and len(s) == 3:
        x[i] = s.replace("ئ","ء")
    if s.endswith("ىء") and len(s) >= 5:
        x[i] = s.replace("ىء","ئ")
```

Now the whole sentence is in `x`:

```
print(' '.join(x))
```

This allows you to define multiple replacements that could apply to the same word, but lets you print the whole modified sentence at the end.

Comment: The information in this answer is true, but I don't think it actually explains the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
for s in x:
  if s.endswith("ئ") and len(s)==3 :
    print(s.replace("ئ","ء"))
  if s.endswith("ىء") and len(s)>=5:
    print(s.replace("ىء","ئ"))
```

It looks like you're splitting the string into words and performing replacements on each word based on specific criteria. However, if there isn't a replacement defined for a word, you never print it. You need a case for the words where you don't replace any characters:

```
for s in x:
  if s.endswith("ئ") and len(s)==3 :
    print(s.replace("ئ","ء"))
  elif s.endswith("ىء") and len(s)>=5:
    print(s.replace("ىء","ئ"))
  else:
    print(s)
```

If you want to put all the output on one line, you can build a list of processed words, re-join them with spaces, and print the result:

```
l = []
for s in x:
  if s.endswith("ئ") and len(s)==3 :
    l.append(s.replace("ئ","ء"))
  elif s.endswith("ىء") and len(s)>=5:
    l.append(s.replace("ىء","ئ"))
  else:
    l.append(s)
print(' '.join(l))
```